# Bat file to create folder (looking for a certain name) from different file types and move files to the correct new folder

Tags: batch-file

I am a noob when it comes to programing so please forgive me (searched all day on the web, could not find anything to help) I have thousands of files that need to go in folders.

This is what I am looking for.

1. create new folders from files, if the folder does not already exist.
2. all folder will be labeled DX1234 and TX1234, the 1234 will vary from 0 to 9. (e.g. DX1942 or TX3142).
3. each file will not start with DX or TX. it will be some were in the file name.
4. file ext. will range from Outlook folders, txt, doc, xlxs, pdf, jpeg.
5. files will move to their new or existing folder.
6. the Bat file will be placed with the files, so no new dir will be needed.
7. can be used by different users, who ever is logged in at the time.
8. can not use any other program due to policy.

please help, and thank you in advance

Comment: Try to explain more detailed. For example, what does "create new folders from files" mean? Should script get folder name from content of the file? Which file?

Comment: Please clarify the question if you want a helpful answer, at the moment it is not at all clear what your objectives are.

Comment: maybe a few examples could help.

Comment: here are two files, keeping in mind that all the files are not label the same.

Comment: here are two files, in this case they are email folders (keeping in mind that all the files are not label the same)..file 1. FW  NTP - NOTICE TO PROCEED CONSTRUCTION @ HEARNE TX1  4129  547648  DX5760 FA#10131398..file 2. FW  NTP Review and Acknowledgement   BU # 807457   AT&T Mobility Zaragoza Tower TX1917   App #200254   Job #245632..i need the script to look for the DX and TX numbers in the file name, then make and label the folder with the DX or TX numbers...and move all the different files types with the same DX or TX number in the correct folder. all my files will be in one folder.

Comment: In your first example file name there is ` TX1 ` AND ` DX5760 `. How to distiguish wheather it's a "TX"file or a "DX"file? Is the `TX` wrong because it has only one number? Is the " DX" correct because it`s after "TX"? Are there other files, where there is a "wrong" `TX` (or `DX`) with more than one number?

Comment: there will always be 4 numbers after the DX or TX,anything short or longer of that will not be the correct DX or TX number. the file name will never have DX**** and TX**** in the same file name. it will always be one or the other...I hope this helps, and thank you for your patients.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b *DX* *TX*') do (
  for %%w in (%%f) do (
    echo "%%w"|findstr "[TD]X[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\>">nul && (
      md %%w 2>nul
      move "%%f" %%w 1>nul 2>nul
    )
  )
)
```

The first `for` creates a list of all the files (some may be there two times, if they have a "TX" and a "DX" in their name, but that's no problem)

The second `for` takes the filename (%%f) and splits it into words (%%w)

Then it checks every word, if it matches the pattern (DX or TX followed by four numbers)

If it matches (`&&`) then create the directory "%%w" (`2>nul`:supress the errormessage if it already exists) and moves the file (%%f) to it. (supress the "1 file copied" (`1>nul`) and any errormessages (`2>nul`) if the file already exists in the destination)

Comment: @Djizeus: I was just writing... ^^

Comment: this is what it is doing on a lot of the folder names. 1st issue, folder name: #DX0687,file name: Cust #DX0687 FA. the folder name can not have the # sign in it. 2nd issue, I have 3 e.g. of this problem, folder: (DX0390, file: (DX0390 FA#10140301).folder: (DX0192),file: 183 (DX0192) FA. folder: TX1107), file: 882 (FA#10000477 TX1107). the folder names can not have any (). 3rd issue, folder: DX4839-FA#10550305-US, file: DX4839-FA#10550305-US Hwy.folder: DX6057_2014 2C LTE Turbo, file: DX6057_2014 2C LTE Turbo. when the file has a _ or - after the DX or TX number, its copying the hole file name.

Comment: Sorry, I worked with your examples. None of them had one of those issues. All of them were pretty formatted with spaces around the TX and DX part. Maybe it is sufficient to adapt the `delims`.

Comment: i tried it again with 850 files. it still makes the folders as I explain above..i did some research trying to understand your comment of "Maybe it is sufficient to adapt the delims". I could not find anything to help me understand. could you explain please? and thanks again for the help and patients.

Comment: `delims` tells `for` where to split the tokens (words). If you change the second `for %%w...` to `for /f "delims= #_" %%w in ('echo %%f`) it will split your filename not only by spaces, but also by `#` and `_`.

Comment: I changed out the second line like you said, but its not working at all now. I don't think I'm replacing correctly, either to much or not enough. if you don't mind could you edit the script